# Compare each line of one file with each line of another file python

Tags: python

I want to compare each number of each line of file to each number of each line of another file. Each line in the first file has some numbers separated by space and the second file is also same:
For example:

file1.txt:

```
10 20 30
100 200 300
1000 2000 3000
```

file2.txt:

```
15 30 40
120 215 315
27 25 35
```

Compare 10 20 30 with

```
15 30 40
120 215 315
27 25 35
```

and so on. What could be the simplest way to implement it?
compare as in: get the difference of each element of each line and print the line if lets say( 1st element of line 1 of first file - 1st element of line 1 of second file < 10 and 2nd element of line 1 of first file - 2nd element of line 1 of second file < 10 and 3rd element of line 1 of first file - 3rd element of line 1 of second file (if all this condition satisfies for each line) then print out the line for which the condition satisfies

Expected output:

```
10 20 30
```

(as 1st line of file1.txt in dir1 satisfies the condition with only the first line of file2.txt in dir2 where 10-15<=10 and 20-30<=10 and 30-40=10<=10 ( consider all modulus)

Comment: Compare and then what? What is your expected output?

Comment: compare as in: get the difference of each element of each line and print the line if lets say( 1st element of line 1 of first file - 1st element of line 1 of second file < 10 and 2nd  element of line 1 of first file - 2nd element of line 1 of second file < 10 and  3rd element of line 1 of first file - 3rd element of line 1 of second file (if all this condition satisfies for each line) then print out the line for which the condition satisfies